# Do I really need to put unit on the graphic?

Tags: data-visualization, units

I would like to add unit on this graphic:
[image]

As stated in many sources, I should place as much of the required information within the figure itself. Unit is a (very) important information so therefore I need to put it on the graphic. But where? I have a feeling that anywhere the unit is, it will make the graphic, erg, imperfect. And I think putting it in the caption won't harm the eye of readers. So do I really need to put it on the graphic?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, put it on the figure.  It is useless without units.  There is plenty of space in the middle of the black bar between the -5.000 and 5.000 .

Comment: Very creative. However, if the size of the graphic is smaller, I'm afraid that people can't read it.